# Grouping rows together based on time stamp

Tags: vba, excel

So im working with some logged data over a few weeks and I am trying to organize the data into an easier to read view as the data is skewed over time due to the fact that all the different points log at a different time (every few seconds)

This is what my data looks like [image: Example]

Is there any VBA code or excel functions to group the data together into a single row based on the minute of the time rather than the second?

Here i used the `=FLOOR(A1, "0:1")` to round the timestamps to the minute.

[image: Time stamps modified]

Now I just want to organize the data so all the row data at 12:57 will be in 1 row rather than 7.

[image: Time stamps merged idea]

Answer (score 0):

he easiest way would be with a pivot table. Just put new time as the row label and the other columns as Sigma values. Since the numbers only occur once for each time, you should get the same answer using max, min or sum for the value field settings.

To avoid the times that aren't used, set up a helper column with the formula

```
=count(C2:J2)
```

starting in (say) L2 and use this as a filter in the pivot table.

Problem I can see though is that data for 13:05 and 13:06 are divided between two different minutes so won't work properly.

You can get round this by using another helper column to pick up just the first time value for a group and copy it down through the rest of the group:-

```
=IF(L2=1,IF(OR(L1=0,ISTEXT(L1)),B2,M1),"")
```

starting in M2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good idea but I dont think this work. My picture is cut off and doesnt display the entire excel. I have 10,000 + rows, and i have a new value for each column approximately every 10-20 rows. Im going to have to write a python script to organize it i think

Comment: I see what you mean. You could maybe get round it by using a helper column that counted the number of non-empty cells in the current row of data and filtering the pivot table on that, so it ignored empty rows.

Comment: Good luck with the Python, but I've further realised that Floor won't work in general because whatever value you choose you can think of a set of times that will get split either side of it.